# Can we catch/log this exception in Edge JS FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: c#, node.js, edgejs

In my .Net application I am using [Edge.JS](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/) to execute a NodeJs program. If an exception of type "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" arises the .Net application is unable to catch/log it and the .Net Process is killed abruptly. Is there a way in NodeJs or EdgeJs to notify the .Net Application that a Fatal Exception has occurred.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if it applies in this case, but you should generally never catch fatal exceptions. It is a deadly sin of exception handling wich will only lead to more and less understandable followup errors. Or at worst: inconsistent data and behavior! Of course as this is only a exception from Java Script, it might just count as a exogenous exception. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx | http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @Christopher if it cannot be catched I would like to atleast log it, how else you will know the reason for process termination?